# Handler not firing on key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate an input form on a keyup handler, but my event is not firing. I'm trying to change the image based on the validity of the users input.
I can log my input variable, but my handler still doesn't work?

HTML

```html
<template id="tmplt">
      <form method="post" action="process_user_form_submission.php" class="modal_form">
            <div class="modal_form-container">
              <div class="modal__form-input-title">
                <span class="modal_spans modal_form-name-span">First and Last Name</span>
                <img src="src/images/circle-form.png" class="modal__form--invalid">
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="modal__input modal_form-container-name form-control form-control-success" required>
            </div>
      </form>
    </template>
```

JS

```js
(function($) {


    var dom;

    // cache necessary dom nodes for this module
    var cacheDOM = function() {
        dom = {};
        dom.document = $(document);
        dom.template = dom.document.find('#tmplt');
        dom.inputModal = dom.template.find('.modal__input');
        dom.formCircle = dom.template.find('.modal__form--invalid');
    };

    // change image based on validity of user input
    var inputModalValid = function() {
        var node = dom.template.prop('content');
        var $input = $(node).find('.modal__input');
        var $check = $(node).find('.modal__form--invalid');
        $input.on('keyup', function() {

            if ($input[0].checkValidity() == true) {
              $check[0].setAttribute("src", 'src/images/checkmark-circle.png');
              console.log($check);
            } else {
                $check[0].setAttribute("src", "src/images/circle-form.png");
              console.log($check);
              
            }
        })
    }

    // initialize the module
    var init = function() {
       cacheDOM();
       inputModalValid();
    };

    init();

    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: can u add your code to `stackoverflow snippet`

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of errors in your code:

1. In `cacheDOM`, you can't use `dom.template.find` to find your elements, because `<template>` elements store their content in a different DOM saved in their `content` property. Therefore, `inputModal` and `formCircle` are both empty `jQuery` objects.
2. In `inputModalValid`, both `$input` and `$check` are empty `jQuery` objects. Consequentially, when you later attempt to attach an event listener for the `keyup` event on `$input`, you don't attach it to any element.

**Code:**

```
(function($) {
  var dom;

  /* Cache the necessary DOM nodes for this module. */
  var cacheDOM = function() {
    dom = {};
    dom.document = $(document);
    dom.template = dom.document.find('#tmplt');
    dom.inputModal = dom.template.find('.modal__input');           // that's empty
    dom.formCircle = dom.template.find('.modal__form--invalid');   // that's empty
  };

  /* Change the image based on the validity of the input's value. */
  var inputModalValid = function() {
    var
      /* Cache the child nodes of the template's own DOM. */
      nodes = $(dom.template.prop('content').children),

      /* Cache the input and the image. */
      $input = nodes.find('.modal__input'),
      $check = nodes.find('.modal__form--invalid');

    /* Set an event listener for the 'keyup' event. */
    $input.on('keyup', function() {
      /* Check the validity of the input. */
      if (this.checkValidity() == true) {
        $check.attr("src", 'src/images/checkmark-circle.png');
      } else {
        $check.attr("src", "src/images/circle-form.png");
      }
    });
  }

  /* Initialize the module. */
  cacheDOM();
  inputModalValid();
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: But when I log $input to the console, it comes up?

Comment: For me it didn't. Perhaps the behaviour is inconsistent across browsers. Also, I suppose you remove the form from the `template` somewhere in your code and add it to the body for it to be rendered, because otherwise how do you know that `keyup` doesn't fire?